# getting error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

Tags: java

I am beginner in Java and I am trying to make a simple sorting program. But I am having trouble while giving input to an array that has to sorted.

Here I have 2 files `App.java` and `Sorting.java`

**App.java**

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Sorting s = new Sorting();
        s.getData();
        s.showData();
    }
}
```

**Sorting.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sorting {
    private 
    int n;
    int[] array = new int[n];

    public
     void getData(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of Array to be Sorted");
        n = input.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println("Enter elements of an array ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }


     void showData(){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Sorted Array => "+ array[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(n);
  

      }
    }
```

But when I compile it and trying to give values to the array, I end-up with an error which says:-

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0                                     ndex 0 out of bounds for length 0
at Sorting.getData(Sorting.java:16)
at App.main(App.java:4)**

It'll be great if someone can point me out that what's wrong I am doing ?

Comment: You create the array of size n = 0 before reading the value you're entering.

Comment: Your array will be initialized to have size zero as there is no value. You should initialize the array *after* getting n from the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is of size 0:

```
int n;  // same as: int n = 0;
int[] array = new int[n];
```

That's why `array[i] = input.nextInt();` will always give an error; you cannot index into an empty array.